# MYSQL - Get last result from each distinct id

Tags: mysql

I trying to get the last result (balance) of each distinct account on the table (example bellow). I tried using **GROUP BY** but it returns the first rows finded.

My expected result is him to return me the rows 4 (last balance from account 2) and row 5 (last balance from account 1), instead it return the rows 
1 and 3 (first balance from each account)

SQL used:

```
select * from sample_table group by account_id;
```

Sample Table:

```
+-------------+------------+
| id | account_id | balance|
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 |          1 | 100.00 |
|  2 |          1 | 150.00 |
|  3 |          2 |  50.00 |
|  4 |          1 | 130.00 |
|  5 |          2 |  70.00 |
+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Assuming, `id` is the primary key. Can I know the id generation strategy used?

Comment: id is auto_increment and the account_id is an foreign key from another table, also auto_increment.

Comment: Go through this once https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/7725942

Comment: Use proper `GROUP BY`.  How can you `SELECT *` in a `GROUP BY`???  In your example, for `account_id` 1, which `id` and `balance` is chosen???  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: GROUP BY is not the point, I tried to use it but did not work. By the way, thanks you all by the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM sample_table t1 LEFT JOIN sample_table t2
 ON (t1.account_id = t2.account_id AND t1.id < t2.id)
WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Worked just perfect for my case. Thanks